# Why won't my tabs work?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying the tab example from semantic ui but I can't make it work. the tabs don't change. did I forget to include something?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu .item').tab();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.2/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
  <a class="item active" data-tab="first">First</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="second">Second</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="third">Third</a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="first">
  First
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="second">
  Second
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="third">
  Third
</div>
```

Comment: @CarolMcKay I fixed it when I cleaned the code. Maybe it was some override or js that didn't work. Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive you need to call this

```
$(function () {
   $('.menu .item').tab();
});
```

to make your tabs works.

And [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/examples) have great documentation you should look there.

Comment: But where should that code be? I tried running it and it doesn't solve the problem. The tabs just don't switch like they are supposed to.

Comment: @Programmer400 I added the place this code should be, if it's still doesn't work can you please edit you code with only the thins that is necessary to your problem.